# How to separate public and admin modules in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm building an app with `CI_v3`. I need to separate admin and public interfaces on the same CI package.

Where:
public URL: `http://example.com/controller/method`
admin URL: `http://example.com/admin/controller/method`

I've searched a lot and found many solutions but not a fully explained one.
How can I do this?

Comment: Where is your problem? Just put your admin controllers inside `application/controllers/admin/whatever.php` and it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Separating the controllers by using an additional folder won't prevent a user from getting to the controllers. What you need is authentication and access control. In other words, some kind of user login system coupled with a system that grants access to certain controllers only if the logged-in user has the correct permission.

There are multiple third-party packages available for CI_v3 that will supply these features. Google "codeigniter authentication" to find them. *Ion_Auth* and *Community Auth* are two of the more popular and robust packages.